# PHP file upload issues/file permissions

Tags: php

Having some script issues with file upload (and/or) file permissions on local XAMPP server - reports error on file upload. Again, user folder is created upon successful registration with this script (Note, this is just registration script, user is not logged in after registration):

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) VALUES('$uname','$email','$upass')")) {

 ?>
     <script>alert('Successfully registered');</script>
 <?php

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$foldername = $_POST['uname'];
$path = "users/";
$complete = $path.$foldername;

if (mkdir($complete, 0777)) {
  ?>
     <script>alert('Folder <?php echo "\"$foldername\""; ?> has been created';</script>
  <?php
}
  else {
   ?>
     <script>alert(Folder not created);</script>
   <?php
}               
}
```

And this is roughly part of the script for file upload when user is logged in:

```
    session_start();

$userfolder = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/users/".$_SESSION['user'];
$filename = $_FILES['filep']['name'];
$filedir = $userfolder.'/'.$filename;

echo "$filedir".'<br />'.'<br />';

//echo getcwd();

    if ($_POST['action'] == "Load") {

        if (file_exists($filedir)) {
            ?>
                <script>alert('File" <?php echo $_FILES['filep']['name'] . "already exists."; ?>');</script>
            <?php
        }
            elseif (!is_writable($filedir)) {
                die ("Not writable !");
            }
                elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filep']['tmp_name'], $filedir)) {
                                ?>
                                    <script>alert('File "<?php echo "$filename"; ?> "loaded');</script> 
}
```

Im using local XAMPP installation C:/xampp/... and echoed $filedir reports C:/xampp/htdocs/users/testuser/, so file path should be OK, but im still getting error from ´is_writable´ and ´move_uploaded_file functions´. Maybe is worth to mention that $_SESSION['user'] in file path is populated in another file script:

```
        if (isset($_POST['btn-login'])) {
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");
        $num = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

            if ($num['password'] == $upass) {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $num['username'];
                header ("Location: home.php");
            }
```

Any hints ? Thank you

Comment: btw what is the error?

Comment: `Warning: move_uploaded_file(C:/xampp/htdocs/users/testuser/file.docx): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\powerlab\addfile.php on line 26`

`Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php49F9.tmp' to 'C:/xampp/htdocs/users/testuser/file.docx' in C:\xampp\htdocs\powerlab\addfile.php on line 26`

Comment: and `is_writable` also returns echoed error

Comment: Does this folder "testuser" exists in "C:/xampp/htdocs/users/"? also make sure its not read-only

Comment: Yes, folder is created, but i cant seem to upload files to it. I can edit Windows permissions, but maybe  issue is on XAMPP/Apache level ?

Comment: please try to upload once again after Edit folder permissions >> security tab >> Edit >> Select EVERYONE and allow Full control.

Comment: Just did that, still error.

Comment: try replacing the directory separator '/' by '\'

Comment: Twas relative path issue :S